# Matplotlib and Celluloid show strange behavior on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to animate the results of a simulation performed with Python. To do so, I'm using matplotlib to generate the frames of the animation and then I collect them with the Camera class from celluloid library. The code that generates the animation is the following:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

camera = Camera(fig)

for i in range(result.t.size):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        x = result.y[0, i]
        y = result.y[1, i]

        plt.scatter(x, y, s = 100, c = 'red')
        plt.xlim(-3, 3)
        plt.ylim(-3, 3)
        plt.grid()

        camera.snap()

animation = camera.animate(blit = False, interval = 10)
HTML(animation.to_html5_video())
```

The last part that generates an HTML5 video allows for watching the animation in a Jupyter notebook on the web. However, I get the following output:

[image]

The first output is the corresponding animation, which is working good. The second is just a static empty plot. So I have two questions:

1. Where does the second plot come from and how can I remove it?
2. The animation is not showing any grid, though I requested it via `plt.grid()` on each frame. Why is that happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: And please review https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html to proper set up a figure.

Comment: `plt.scatter(x, y, s = 100, c = 'red')` should probably be `ax.scatter(x, y, s = 100, c = 'red')`. You create a figure and axes, and then never use it.

Answer (score 0):

Call plt.close() to avoid showing the unused figure, before displaying the animation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).